# Addition in conditional plotting in Gnuplot forces "No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range"

Tags: if-statement, plot, conditional-statements, gnuplot

I use a simple code to create a series of images from one file, depending on the condition. While doing so I realized that:

```
splot [1:150][1:150][] "dinozaur" u 5:6:(($4==0.4+0.0025*3)?$2:1/0)
```

...does not work but:

```
splot [1:150][1:150][] "dinozaur" u 5:6:(($4==0.40750)?$2:1/0)
```

...works.

However, both

```
splot [1:150][1:150][] "dinozaur" u 5:6:(($4==0.5+0.0025*3)?$2:1/0)
```

...and

```
splot [1:150][1:150][] "dinozaur" u 5:6:(($4==0.50750)?$2:1/0)
```

work.

If I get an error, its the one in the title.
Is there some kind of obvious mistake that I am doing ?

Im enclosing a snippet of data file with column 4 having values of 0.40750
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpv0m2wfoo3qwl7/dinozaur?dl=0

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to clarify your problem a bit. This might help you finding answers fast. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic on a computer is not exact. For example, 0.4+0.0025*3 might not be exactly the same as 0.40750. For detailed information, take a look at this question: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

You generally want to avoid testing floating point numbers for strict equality. Instead, you can test is two numbers are sufficiently close. For example,

```
eps = 1E-10
splot [1:150][1:150][] "dinozaur" u 5:6:((abs($4 - (0.4+0.0025*3)) < eps) ? $2 : 1/0)
```

should work.